# json requested via Ajax: queries are very fast but response is returned very slowly

Tags: laravel, api, performance, nginx, laravel-8

Note this
[image]

[image]

It's a single ajax request.

As you can see, I wrote the `duration` in the result, it's the duration of *all* the queries executed in the api backend.

The Response length is `11 KByte`, so it's not a response weight problem.

But as you can see the server is serving the page is `5 seconds`.

I'm using nginx, and on this server (it's a single project dev VPS), there is NO trafic, no concurrency problems.

The backend is made in laravel 8 and it's doing only this:

```
    $start = microtime(true);
    $data = $this->articleRepository->getProducts($request->all());
    $duration = microtime(true) - $start;

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'data' => $data,
        'debug' => [
            'duration' => $duration
        ]
    ]);
```

I tried to replace laravel magics with

```
    $json = json_encode([
        'status' => 'success',
        'data' => $data,
        'debug' => [
            'duration' => $duration
        ]
    ]);

    return $json;
```

But it's taking same time. So I *think* that is a problem at server side.

> By the way, please note that dev VPS is a debian 11 machine *in my local network*. We already verified that up/down band is well over 350Mbits/secs, symmetric, and stable.

I cannot diagnose it, I have root access to VPS, but I've no idea of what could causes so  much slowness

Any idea?

Comment: Laravel might be lazy loading your `$data` models. Meaning they might not be requesting some data (think other models set as a relationship) until they are explicitly requested in code aka during your response->json call. Check out Eloquent Eager Loading in the docs - https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Nope, I tried echoing a "Hello" and TTFB is still >4 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this very specific case, it was a question of DNS. "localhost" resolution are causing a series of problems and latencies. We moved all pointing from 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1 and ALL is resolved.

> Note for future Googlers for Laragon and/or Xamp developers: we discovered accidentally that changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 when configuring redis in the laravel .env variabile fixes a huge amount on a windows machine when using both Laragon and Xamp